# How to use selected columns in sub query using sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

im using sub query to return average amount and total amount between two dates, when returning average amount i have to use the selected columns in sub query.

Below is the i have tried.

```
tbl_batch_charges
merchant_id total_transaction_amount  settlement_date 
1         33.65                        2014-07-01
1         33.65                        2014-07-10
2         39.36                        2014-07-15


merchant_application_form
merchant_id   active_date
1              2013-10-20
2              2014-01-10

Resulted Table
merchant_id  weekly_transaction  total_turnover
1             xx                 67.3
2             xx                 39.36      


select tbl_batch.merchant_id,
   tbl_merchant.merchant_application_form_active_date,
   GETDATE() as today_date,  
   (select sum(tbl_batch.total_transactions_amount) from Borgun.dbo.tbl_batch_charges as tbl_batch 
   where tbl_batch.settlement_borgun_date between '2014-07-01' and '2014-10-20' and 
   tbl_batch.merchant_id='9947230') as weekly_total_amount,
   (select (sum(tbl_batch.total_transactions_amount)/(ceiling(convert(float, abs(datediff(day, active_date, today_date)))/7)))) as total_turn_over 
   from Borgun.dbo.tbl_batch_charges as tbl_batch 
   left join Borgun.dbo.tbl_merchant_application_form as tbl_merchant  on tbl_merchant.merchant_application_form_merchant_id=tbl_batch.merchant_id 
   where tbl_batch.merchant_id='9947230' group by tbl_batch.merchant_id;
```

**I want the merchant total turn over average from the date he joined to current date on weekly basis. **

can you please tell me how will i solve that in sql server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: edited the question please check it once

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your question is, but rewriting your code into the below syntax might work

```
SELECT
    tbl_batch.merchant_id,  
    tbl_merchant.merchant_application_form_active_date, 
    GETDATE() AS today_date,
    sum(tbl_batch.total_transactions_amount) as total_amount,
    avg(tbl_batch.total_transactions_amount) as average_amount
FROM 
    Borgun.dbo.tbl_batch_charges tbl_batch
    LEFT JOIN Borgun.dbo.tbl_merchant_application_form tbl_merchant on tbl_batch.merchant_id = tbl_merchant.merchant_application_form_merchant_id
WHERE
    Settlement_borgun_date between '2014-07-01' and '2014-10-20' 
    and tbl_batch.merchant_id='9947230'
GROUP BY
    tbl_batch.merchant_id,  
    tbl_merchant.merchant_application_form_active_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT
    tbl_batch.merchant_id,  
    total_turnover = AVG(tbl_batch.total_transactions_amount),
    weekly_transaction = SUM(tbl_batch.total_transactions_amount)
    FROM Borgun.dbo.tbl_batch_charges as tbl_batch 
        LEFT JOIN Borgun.dbo.tbl_merchant_application_form as tbl_merchant  
            ON tbl_merchant.merchant_application_form_merchant_id=tbl_batch.merchant_id 
        WHERE tbl_batch.merchant_id='9947230' 
            AND tbl_batch.settlement_borgun_date between '2014-07-01' and '2014-10-20'
    GROUP BY tbl_batch.merchant_id,
                tbl_merchant.merchant_application_form_active_date
```

Comment: So you want the SUM of the total_Transaction_Amount but the AVG of something else or some different set of values ?